# Is $S=\sum_{r=1}^\infty \tan^{-1}\frac{2r}{2+r^2+r^4}$ finite?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, trigonometry

**Problem**:
If  $$S=\sum_{r=1}^\infty \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2r}{2+r^2+r^4}\right)$$ Then find S ??

**Solution**:

I know that $\tan^{-1} x + \tan^{-1} y= \tan^{-1} \frac {x +y}  {1-xy} $

But I have no idea how to such complicated question with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT:

As $1+a^2+a^4=(1+a^2)^2-a^2=(1+a^2-a)(1+a^2+a),$

$$\frac{2\cdot a}{2+a^2+a^4}=\frac{(1+a^2+a)-(1+a^2-a)}{1+(1+a^2-a)(1+a^2+a)}$$

$$\implies \arctan \left(\frac{2\cdot a}{2+a^2+a^4}\right)=\arctan(1+a^2+a)-\arctan(1+a^2-a)$$

Can you recognize the [Telescoping series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)?

So, $$\sum_{1\le r\le n}\arctan \left(\frac{2\cdot r}{2+r^2+r^4}\right)=\arctan (1+n^2+n)-\arctan 1$$
$$=\arctan\left(\frac{n^2+n}{n^2+n+2}\right)=\arctan\left(\frac{1+\frac1n}{1+\frac1n+\frac2{n^2}}\right)$$

$$\implies \lim_{n\to\infty}\arctan\left(\frac{1+\frac1n}{1+\frac1n+\frac2{n^2}}\right)=\arctan1=\frac\pi4$$

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9170/discussion-between-lab-bhattacharjee-and-rst)

Comment: Thanks a lot ,its really helpful